# Colimit of isomorphisms is an isomorphism (as objects in the arrow category)

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category. Consider the [arrow category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category) $Fun([1], C)$ (where $[1]$ is the category $\bullet\to\bullet$). The objects in this category are the morphisms in $C$. The proof in [Kerodon 0064](https://kerodon.net/tag/0064) suggests that a colimit of objects in $Fun([1], C)$, which are isomorphisms in $C$, is again an isomorphism of $C$. Is this true? Where can I find a reference?

Comment: The proof actually uses the dual statement, that the limit of isomorphisms is an isomorphism. Note that in either case the statement is true, since an isomorphism of diagrams induces an isomorphism of (co)limits. (Hm. you do have to be a bit careful if $C$ is not (co)complete, but the existence of a (co)limit in the arrow category should imply the existence of the (co)limits of the start and end diagrams as well.)

Comment: "since an isomorphism of diagrams induces an isomorphism of (co)limits" what do you mean here? is "isomorphism" here an isomorphism in the arrow category or an object in the arrow category that happens to be an isomorphism in C? The definition of "diagram" I know defines diagrams as functors. So you are saying "an isomorphism of functors induces an isomorphism of (co)limits" -- but an isomorphism *of which* functor induces an isomorphism *of which* (co)limits?

Comment: "The proof actually uses the dual statement, that the limit of isomorphisms is an isomorphism" You are right that I should have said "limit" instead of "colimit". But I don't think that's the *dual* statement, because one can only dualize purely *categorical* statements and properties. Being an object of the arrow category that is an isomorphism when considered as a morphism in C is *not* a categorical property.

Comment: Does this statement follow from some general statement that I can find in some book?

Comment: In my experience, when most people say the dual of a statement they typically mean dualizing the categorical parts of the statement and leaving the rest of the statement alone. But regardless, being an isomorphism is in fact a categorical property of objects in the arrow category in several ways. Firstly, the arrow category admits a first arrow, second arrow and composition functor from the composable pairs of arrows category, which we can use to detect isomorphisms. Secondly, the isomorphisms are precisely those objects in the essential image of the diagonal map from the base category.

Comment: As for what I meant by an isomorphism of diagrams, a diagram of isomorphisms in the arrow category is equivalently regarded as an isomorphism of the two diagrams in the base category you get by applying the start and end functors to the diagram in the arrow category.

Answer (score 2):

A diagram in $\mathrm{Fun}([1],C)$ is a functor $H:I → \mathrm{Fun}([1],C)$ which is equivalently given by a functor $I × [1] → C$.
This in turn is equivalent to the datum of two functors $F,G:I → C$ together with a natural transformation $α:F ⇒ G$.
Assuming that $F$ and $G$ admit colimits in $C$, the natural transformation $α$ induces a morphism $\mathrm{colim}(F) → \mathrm{colim}(G)$ via the universal property of $\mathrm{colim}(F)$.
This morphism is the colimit of our original diagram in $\mathrm{Fun}([1],C)$.
(This is a special case of (the proof of) the statement, that a (co)limit of a diagram of functors exists already if it exists objectwise.)

Now, our original diagram $I → \mathrm{Fun}([1],C)$ has only isomorphism arrows as objects if and only if the corresponding natural transformation $α$ is a natural isomorphism.
Using the universal property of colimits again, one shows that the induced morphism $\mathrm{colim}(F) → \mathrm{colim}(G)$ is an isomorphism.